# Unix/Linux API for file/runtime permissions

Tags: c++, c, linux, api, unix

I want to write memory in `/proc/$pid/mem` but I assume this will need superuser root privileges.   Is there an API to test if the program has the permission to edit these files?

Answer (score 2):

You can `stat()` the pathname and the `st_mode` field of the outcoming `struct stat` contains the permission bits. See manpage `stat(2)` for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
int access(const char *path, int amode);
```

where path is your filename and amode is a bitwise inclusive OR of access permissions to check against.

R_OK, W_OK, and X_OK hold mode values for checking read, write, and search/execute permissions respectively.

```
int readable, readwritable;

//checking for read access
readable = access("/usr/bin/file", R_OK);

//checking for read and write access
readwritable = access("/usr/bin/file", R_OK|W_OK);
```

For full description of access() check man pages.